# Assume pixel is circular in Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: python, matlab, fft, pixel

I'm trying to calculate holograms through an iterative algorithm that applies FFT. Holograms are calculated though based on square signals(pixels). I want to calculate FFT from  a signal ( a pixel ) but i want its FFT to be the FFT of a circular "pixel".

What ive tried os far is to take a 64x64 pixels hologram, enlarge it by 31 times (1984x1984) and create a circle with central point the pixel.

I want to avoid that rescaling.
 Although the smaller the size of the rescaled image the less accurate the circle is.

```
I=imread('MM.bmp'); I=imresize(I,[64 64 ],'Method', 'nearest');
I=I./max(max(I)); 
avg1=mean(mean(I));
I1=I;
ph=rand([size(I,1),size(I,2)]);
U=I1.*exp(1j*ph);

for n=1:700
        n1=n1+1;
U1= fftshift(fft2(fftshift(U)));
U2=fftshift(ifft2(fftshift(exp(1j*angle(U1)))));
avg2=mean(mean(abs(U2)));
U3=(U2./avg2).*avg1;
U=I.*exp(1j.*angle(U3));
end
imwrite(angle(U1), 'HOLOGRAM.jpg')
```

when i will use the fft on a pixel signal, i want to get the fft of a circle not the sinc function from the square signal.`

Comment: How does this relate to `python`? the code is exclusively matlab.. Also this may be more of a math problem than a coding problem you might consider posting on https://math.stackexchange.com/ (I say this only from the standpoint of "I understand conceptually what you are saying, but I don't know the proper mathematical way to solve it. If I knew the proper mathematical way to solve it, I imagine I would have no problem implementing it in code")

Comment: `U` is used before it is defined, and you compute lots of stuff you don’t use later. Please see [mre] and then [edit] your question accordingly. With the broken and obfuscated code it’s hard to understand what you’re doing there.

Comment: forgot to paste few lines :( .

I believe the solution in python would be similar to matlab's. And yes i believe it a more of a mathematical problem.